# Log (log4j & Java) level changes at run time not honored by classes inside vendor jar

Tags: java, log4j

I created a servlet to change the log level at runtime and below is the snipet of code that does the reinitialization.

```
            String propertyFile = request.getParameter("log4jproperties");
            Properties log4jProperties = new Properties();
            log4jProperties.load(new StringReader(propertyFile));
            LogManager.resetConfiguration();                
            PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jProperties);
            logger.info("Hello at info");
            logger.error("Hello at error");
            System.out.println("Configured Succesfully ");
```

I have set the debug flag to true.

```
      -Dlog4j.debug
```

When I change the log level , I see the re initialization of log4j running with the new properties I passed in the servlet. I also see that the "Hello" log messages in the servlet corresponding to the log level passed in the properties.

```
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:487 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4jProperties.size()18
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:487 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[ERROR,Portal,console].
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:487 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: Level token is [ERROR].
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:487 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: Category root set to ERROR
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:487 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: Parsing appender named "Portal".
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:487 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: Parsing layout options for "Portal".
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:487 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [[%d{MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss.SSS }] %t [%p]%m%n].
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:487 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: End of parsing for "Portal".
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:487 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: Setting property [maxFileSize] to [100MB].
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:487 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: Setting property [maxBackupIndex] to [20].
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:487 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: Setting property [file] to [/applogs/MemberPortal/MemberPortal.log].
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:487 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: setFile called: /applogs/MemberPortal/MemberPortal.log, true
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:487 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: setFile ended
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:487 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: Parsed "Portal" options.
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:487 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: Parsing appender named "console".
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:487 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: Parsing layout options for "console".
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:487 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [[%d{MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss.SSS }] %t %c %r [%p]%m%n].
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:488 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: End of parsing for "console".
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:488 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: Parsed "console" options.
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:488 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: Parsing for [com.BCBSTN.OpenToken] with value=[ERROR,OpenToken,console].
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:488 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: Level token is [ERROR].
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:488 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: Category com.BCBSTN.OpenToken set to ERROR
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:488 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: Parsing appender named "OpenToken".
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:488 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: Parsing layout options for "OpenToken".
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:488 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [[%d{MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss.SSS }] %t [%p]%m%n].
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:488 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: End of parsing for "OpenToken".
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:488 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: Setting property [maxFileSize] to [100MB].
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:488 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: Setting property [file] to [/applogs/OpenToken/OpenToken.log].
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:488 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: Setting property [maxBackupIndex] to [20].
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:488 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: setFile called: /applogs/OpenToken/OpenToken.log, true
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:488 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: setFile ended
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:488 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: Parsed "OpenToken" options.
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:488 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: Parsing appender named "console".
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:488 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: Appender "console" was already parsed.
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:488 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.com.BCBSTN.OpenToken=[false]
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:488 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: Setting additivity for "com.BCBSTN.OpenToken" to false
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:488 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O log4j: Finished configuring.
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:488 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O [10/11/18 15:14:14.488 ] WebContainer : 2 com.bcbst.mp.updateotherinsurance.controller.ResetLog4jSettings 500736 [ERROR]Hello at error
    [10/11/18 15:14:14:489 EDT] 000001ab SystemOut     O Configured Succesfully
```

Here are the log file I passed as a parameter to the servlet.

```
    # Console Configuration
    log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss.SSS }] %t %c %r [%p]%m%n


    #Member Portal Rolling File Configuration
    log4j.appender.Portal=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.Portal.File=/applogs/MemberPortal/MemberPortal.log
    log4j.appender.Portal.MaxFileSize=100MB
    log4j.appender.Portal.MaxBackupIndex=20
    log4j.appender.Portal.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.Portal.layout.ConversionPattern = [%d{MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss.SSS }] %t [%p]%m%n

    #Open Token Rolling File Configuration
    log4j.appender.OpenToken=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.OpenToken.File=/applogs/OpenToken/OpenToken.log
    log4j.appender.OpenToken.MaxFileSize=100MB
    log4j.appender.OpenToken.MaxBackupIndex=20
    log4j.appender.OpenToken.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.OpenToken.layout.ConversionPattern = [%d{MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss.SSS }] %t [%p]%m%n


    # Root Configuration - All packages
    # Always keep this configuration
    log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,Portal,console

    #  OPEN TOKEN is a shared jar , needs restart of JVM to effect changes in log configuration  #
    log4j.logger.com.BCBSTN.OpenToken=DEBUG,OpenToken,console
    log4j.additivity.com.BCBSTN.OpenToken=false
```

The logs in the vendor jar are at DEBUG level.
What I don't understand is why is the log level changes not picked by the jar dynamically.

I have to change the file  "customlogFile" and restart server for the changes to pick up.

```
      -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/customlogFile.properties
```

The servlet is bundled as a war , with the vendor jar and log4j deployed on server. (so I believe the classloader that loads the classes in the jar and the servlet could be different).

Can some one help me figure out why the log level changes are not honored by the logger in the jar. What am I missing.

Comment: You already answered it yourself: *"the classloader that loads the classes in the jar and the servlet could be different"*. Which means that the vendor jar is using a different instance of Log4j than your webapp, since you have Log4j jar files in both `tomcat/lib` folder and in webapps `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Comment: First off, this is Enterprise IBM Websphere Application Server 9. Since I have set "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/customlogFile.properties" , it overrides the initialization process(search classpath and such for finding log4j.properties) and any other log4j.properties file in the server would not matter. I also looked into the source code of the jar to make sure that they do not have a log4j.property bundled with it and that they are not overriding the initialization process in some way.  Your statement is not applicable in my case.

Comment: @Andreas I also executed find command and I did not find other instances of log4j.jar in the server lib folder or (bundled in some other) EAR/WAR. I found one instance in the shared/app/ location where we typically put the shared artifacts. This shared location is added in the classpath.

Comment: @Andreas  Let me clarify , If I was not clear earlier. There is ONLY ONE instance of the log4j.jar and it is in the shared/app.  We have two log4j.properties in our repository - one for enabling the logs , second for turning it off. I created the property files before the servlet was created. The comments were added when we were ok with restarting the server for the log changes to take place.  I would not be too concerned about the comment now.